# UIImageView subclass touch detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, touch

I have a subclass of `UIImageView` that I need to know when is touched. (Full code below.) I have found and read both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143072/my-uiimageview-doesnt-get-all-the-methods-of-my-subclassed-uiimageview) and [this](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/83/topics/1423). They were mildly useful, but neither really worked. Not only is my `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method not being called, the button behind the image is being pressed.

Here is my code:

Header file:

```
@interface MathKeyboardKey : UIImageView
{

}

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
@implementation MathKeyboardKey

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    if (self = [super initWithImage:image])
    {
        //init here
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"-- I AM TOUCHED --");
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Calling code:

```
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    mathKeyboardAccess = [[MathKeyboardKey alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mathKey.png"]];
    CGRect frm = mathKeyboardAccess.frame;
    frm.origin = CGPointMake(80, 171);
    mathKeyboardAccess.frame = frm;
    mathKeyboardAccess.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:mathKeyboardAccess];
}
```

This view is being added as a subview of another (the `MathKeyboard`). The superview cannot have user interaction enabled, as it is covering another view (the system keyboard). When I attempt to add `MathKeyboardKey` to the system keyboard view, it doesn't show up. If I try to use a UIButton, it never shows up, no matter which view I place it in.

Question, in case it isn't apparent, is: how do I detect touches in this `UIImageView` subclass?

Comment: I'm shotgunning in the dark here; have you tried to set it to first responder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Since you have disabled user interaction of the parent view, how could the child receive any interactions? Remove this line.

Comment: I commented out that line and my button works, but I cannot use anything in the system keyboard. How do I send touches "through" the `MathKeyboard` to the system keyboard?

Comment: @Cajun: Sending messages to the system keyboard is "undocumented". If the target is a text field or text view, modify its `text` property directly.

Comment: Not only is it undocumented, it straight-up doesn't work. I had to add my view as a subview of the keyboard directly.

So the answer doesn't directly answer the question, but it got me on the right path.